# Keyword not supported: 'version'

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I've got this project that I wrote in VS2010 as a WinForms project.  I'm not writing it in VS2012 as a WPF project.  I have a referenced DLL (`DailyReport`).  Inside `DailyReport` is a method called `GetUniqueDates()`.  It looks like this:

```
    public List<string> GetUniquesDates()
    {
        var dates = new List<string>();

        const string query = "SELECT date FROM hdd_local_data_v1_2";

        try
        {
            // Exception here  on the connection creation
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringFile)) 
            {
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                            {
                                dates.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {         
            Logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }

        dates.Sort();

        return dates.Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

The `ConnectionStringFile` is set in the constructor, and looks like this:

```
ConnectionStringFile = @"Data Source=C:\hdd_data\Rubicon.hdd;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";
```

Now, in my VS2010 WinForms project, this method worked just fine.  However, in my VS2012 WPF project, I get an exception where I noted above.  And the exception is:

```
keyword not supported 'version'.
```

The database is a SQLite database.  I've tried removing the `version` keyword, but then I'd get the exception:

```
keyword not supported 'new'.
```

My question is:  Why would the connection work in my WinForms project and not my WPF project?  Is there something that changed when dealing with database connections?

Also, please note, this isn't a question about parameterized queries and the like.  So, if possible, please those comments to yourself.  Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite specifically the last item.

Comment: @MarkKram: As I stated earlier to a guy who posted that as an answer, and then deleted his question, my database is at the path listed in my connection string.  According to that link, the "In-Memory Database" section, I have the correct string.

Comment: Don't you need to use actual SQLite classes to access an SQLite in-memory database? I'm pretty sure Microsoft's standard SqlConnection doesn't have a clue on how to connect to one of those... =)

Comment: @J.Steen: You sir, are a genius.  I knew I was doing something completely silly.  `Data Source` can be the file path, and it works, now that I've changed it from `SqlConnection` to `SQLiteConnection`.  Thank you.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as your own answer. I know nothing of SQLite, and was just making an educated guess, really. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue I was having was because I was trying to create a `SqlConnection` instead of a `SQLiteConnection`.  Making that change solved my issue.