# Activator.CreateInstance throws a "keyword not supported" exception

Tags: c#, unit-of-work, activator

I'm encountering the following exception:

```
keyword not supported: 'name'.
```

It is caused by the 2nd line of the following code:

```
var attr = (ContextAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (TEntity),typeof (ContextAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
context = (DbContext)Activator.CreateInstance(attr.ContextType);
```

attr.ContextType is a Type and is not null. Inside the class represented by attr.ContextType, I have noticed that "Name" was a property of the class, but has been commented out. I don't know if this is a red herring or not -- I noticed that the error very specifically mentions name as a lower-case, but the property, when it isn't commented out, is a capital.

The intent of the code is to load a repository from a UnitOfWork, if that matters.

Also, in case it matters, I didn't write this code, and so it could be something blatantly obvious. I'm not super familiar with the EntityFramework and dependency injection being used in this part of the code. I just happen to depend on this code working correctly for my code to get executed.

Comment: attr.ContextType is a type or a string?

Comment: Sorry, my goof in describing the code. attr.ContextType is a Type. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: It has been fixed now. The guy who wrote the code showed me some sort of custom configuration generator that modified my web.config. It doesn't really answer the question as to what can cause a "Keyword not supported" error, but in my case, apparently it had something to do with the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

See [Keyword not supported: 'version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462818/keyword-not-supported-version). I think you may be having the same issue. Check your DB connection string?