# Entity Framework Core SQLite Connection String Keyword not supported: version

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I created a ASP.NET MVC website using .NET Core 2.2 using a SQLite database. So far it's working well. Trouble begins when I want to add SQLite-specific keywords to the connection string, such as

```
Data Source=~\\App_Data\\MyDb.db; Version=3; DateTimeFormat=UnixEpoch; DateTimeKind=Utc
```

Now I get

> Keyword not supported: 'version'

I register the database like this

```
// ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDB").Replace("~", _env.ContentRootPath);
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(conn));
```

Then MyDBContext has

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDBContext() { }

    public SatrimonoContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
}
```

Then I use it in my page Model

```
private SatrimonoContext _db;

public BookAccuracyListModel(SatrimonoContext dbContext)
{
    _db = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
}
```

and from there I can access _db normally via LINQ.

Before posting here, I did plenty of research on the topic, and the best responses I found were [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/406#issuecomment-324689331)

> This provider is Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. Those connection strings are
>   for System.Data.SQLite.
>
> We support the following keywords: Cache, Data Source, Mode.

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468295/3960200)

> The issue I was having was because I was trying to create a
>   SqlConnection instead of a SQLiteConnection. Making that change solved
>   my issue.

However, if I'm doing it "right", I'm not creating the SqlConnection and thus can't change it to SQLiteConnection. The other response doesn't include a solution.

So how do I get this to work the right way?

Comment: If you found documentation that says that the only keywords supported are x, y and z, why exactly do you think using other keywords will magically work? The only thing I can think of for you to do is not to use `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`, and that will probably mean that you cannot use EF Core

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a thread in [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/issues/406) regarding the issue.

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` only supports three keywords:

- **Cache** - *Private or Shared*
- **Data Source** - *The database file. Can be a URI filename.*
- **Mode** - *ReadWriteCreate, ReadWrite, ReadOnly, or Memory.*

No other keywords are supported for this namespace, however if you use the keywords you mentioned with `System.Data.SQLite` namespace, it will work, as they are keywords matched for `System.Data.SQLite`.

Your two options:

1. Remove the `Version=3` keyword or any other unsupported keyword from the connection string
2. Change the namespace you use for your *SQlite* connection.

Comment: Is System.Data.SQLite compatible with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Yes, you can add the package to your project, follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903863/password-protected-sqlite-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: I tried adding System.Data.SQLite.Core and also System.Data.SQLite to the .NET Core 2.2. project and the namespace doesn't become available. Perhaps it's not compatible with .NET Core?

Comment: Oh, closing Visual Studio and re-opening fixed it. It bugs sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Barr's response, the solution is to add System.Data.SQLite.Core to the project.

Then replace

```
var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Satrimono").Replace("~", _env.ContentRootPath);
services.AddDbContext<SatrimonoContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(conn));
```

with

```
var connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Satrimono").Replace("~", _env.ContentRootPath);
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
services.AddDbContext<SatrimonoContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(conn));
```

That's it!